# how to process Wordpress Password Encryption method for android?

Tags: android, wordpress, authentication, password-encryption

I'm creating an android app which depends on the wordpress website.

I've used normal md5 encryption method for password during user registration.

At once when the user logs in, login process works perfectly. After that, the md5 encrypted password is automatically converted to phpass password. Login affects in the next trail since wordpress site has phpass encryption process.

Is there any way to process both encryption and decryption process in android related to wordpress?

Comment: process flow: md5 password saved in wp-users database table in wordpress.
first attempt to login succeeds.
now, md5 password is automatically converted to phpass(encryption class in wordpress).
then login affects in android app.
but login works in website. Is there a solution?

Comment: You can see this post here. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32004/how-to-validate-wordpress-generated-password-in-db-using-php

Comment: Did you check how [WordPress Android](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android) works?

Comment: couldn't able to frame code(outside of wordpress) for android from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32004/how-to-validate-wordpress-generated-password-in-db-using-php.

Answer (score 0):

Using json api, i can able to login and register into wordpress.

for login, use json api auth plugin

for register user, use json api user plugin